# Алгоритм решения: как найти 100 самых часто встречаемых слов в файле

Tags: python, алгоритм, текст, анализ-данных

Не могу придумать алгоритм для своего кода. Помогите пожалуйста.
У нас есть два файла. Первый с текстом (Длина текста  N слов). Во втором - "синонимы слов". То есть в одном ряду будет написано слово начальной формы,а после- его склонения или синонимы. Например:

- компьютер, компьютером, компьютеру, компьютера, компьютеры
- дом, дома, домом, дому,домашний

Длина этого файла M слов.

Файлы очень большой размерности.
Мне нужно найти 100 самых часто встречаемых слов в первом файле. Если допустим мы нашли слово **компьютер** и **компьютером**, то это посчитается за одно слово (так как во втором файле они стоят в одном ряду, но слово компьютер уже появилось **два раза**) и на выход программы выйдет слово: начальная форма 100 слов, которые встречаются в тексте больше всего.

Помогите найти самый быстрый алгоритм решения (код не нужен, лишь алгоритм). И какая сложность по времени будет исходя из N, M. Заранее благодарю)

Comment: Во-первых, это не синонимы, а формы слова. во-вторых, где ваши попытки решения?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: strawdog, мои попытки решения закончились методом грубой силы, поэтому написала здесь. Либо же сделать сортировку первого и файла O(N*log(N)), и потом опять за линейную временную сложность проверять сортированные слова со словами из второго файла O(N*M+N*log(N)). Это не эффективно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прочитайте второй файл, организовав  словарь, в котором ключи - словоформы (включая начальную), а значения - начальная форма (`{дом:дом; домашний:дом etc}`)

Теперь прочитайте первый файл, для каждого его слова находя соответствующее значение в словаре, и увеличивая для этого значения счётчик в `Counter`.

А у `Counter` есть `most_common`

Comment: То есть временная сложнось будет O(N*M) как я поняла. Ведь мы проходим весть первый файл и второй. Но это метод грубой силы, если числа N и M окажутся слишком большими, то работать алгоритм будет слишком долго.

Comment: Нет, (n+m) для словаря на основе хэш таблиц или (m log(m) + n log (m)) для словарей на основе дерева. Для того и придумали словари

Comment: @Harry Ну это я и имел в виду - dict в питоне на основе хеш-таблиц (почти)линейное время даёт.

Comment: @Kate Единственная проблема, которая может возникнуть - это что в память не влезет таблица перекодировок слов и счётчик. А если в память влезет, то от величин N и M скорость будет зависеть вполне линейно. Коллизии хэша могут немного тормозить, всё-равно сложность алгоритма будет O(N+M)

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо) а если вот как вы сказали, что таблица перекодировок займет больше места, чем память. Можно ли как-то это обойти?

Comment: @Harry спасибо, поняла

Comment: @Kate Из простого можно попробовать использовать *интернализацию строк*, чтобы одинаковые строки не занимали дополнительные место - делать для всех используемых в коде строк такой трюк: `string = sys.intern(string)`, тогда не будет выделяться лишнее место для одинаковых строк. Хотя это может и не помочь, если лишних операций со строками не делать, они и так должны быть у вас в виде одной ссылки каждая. Да, в вашем случае, думаю, это не имеет смысла.

Comment: Не представляю себе как словоформы одного языка не влезут в память. Даже если предположить что у нас 10 миллионов словоформ по 50 символов, то это всего 1 гигабайт памяти. То есть второй файл точно поместится в память. Словарь со счётчиками тоже.